# Running SQL*Plus with bash causes wrong encoding

Tags: oracle, bash, sqlplus

I have a problem with running SQL*Plus in the bash.
Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

 curl http://192.168.168.165:8080/api_test/xsql/f_exp_order_1016.xsql > script.sql
 sqlplus /nolog << ENDL
 connect user/password 
 set sqlblanklines on
 start script.sql
 exit
 <<ENDL
```

I download the insert statements from our intranet, put it into sql file and run it through SQL*Plus. This is working fine. Only problem is that the file script.sql encoding looks like this `application/x-empty; charset=binary` (determined through file -bi). So it's causing inserting wrong characters to my DB which is something I really don't want.

So you could you please tell me how do I change the file encoding withou losing any data?And also any advices regarding to my script are welcomed, I am total newbie in Linux scripting:-)

I also tried change encoding with `iconv` and it didn't helped.

**UPDATE**

I don't know why but I deleted the file, run the script again few times and encoding is suddenly `UTF-8`, but characters are still broken both in file and DB, so it didn't solve anything

Comment: If that's the whole script, why don't you have an end-tag for the here-document (<< ENDL)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste it here. See update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem wasn't in the file (encoding was UTF-8 as it should be) but in the setting of Oracle NLS_LANG environmental variable.
So solution was putting this line before executing SQL*Plus script

`NLS_LANG="CZECH_CZECH REPUBLIC.UTF8" export NLS_LANG`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--data-ascii` switch on the `curl` command.

Comment: No, it didn't work for me, characters are still broken. But thanks for advice